# Using springcloud to manage pods in k8s

Tags: docker, microservices, spring-cloud, istio

I'm doing my school project, which requires me to build an **AI management platform** with requirements listed below:

- microservice architecture
- train and deploy AI in docker
- provide API to access deployed AI models
- AI models version management
- dataset management
- CI/CD

I'm trying to figure out a solution for backend.

Currently I select springcloud to provide backend service.

But I want to know that **can I use springcloud to manage k8s**? If I can, is there two k8s clusters, one for my springcloud project, one for my AI dockers?

Or maybe I should use k8s+istio+ingress+...... to realize this? If so, is there any documentations and examples I can learn from?

Comment: Spring Cloud doesn't manage k8s. If you mean that you want to use Spring Cloud Gateway to direct traffic to services, yes it can do that.

Comment: So Spring Cloud is not necessary in this case? But how can I create a pod when I receive an API call? maybe by using k8s Java SDK in Spring Boot?

Comment: What have you already tried?  https://spring.io/ has fairly extensive documentation; have you looked to see which specific Spring Cloud modules could help you?  I'm guessing, if it's been pre-decided that you need to launch Kubernetes Jobs for training, that you'll directly need to use the Kubernetes API.

Comment: Spring Cloud does not manage k8s pods.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about using some other technology for automatic pod creation based on certain conditions like apache airflow with python, which supports creating new pods using Kubernetes Pod Operator. Each operator can start your spring boot micro services build as docker image.

Example Flow: Airflow ---> Python ---> Kubernetes Pod Operator --> Manage Pods on k8s